# Jars in eclipse dependant project's Web app libraries not being exported

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have created a Dynamic Web App in eclipse. It has 2 jars in it's Web App Libraries folder.
I have selected Web App Libraries folder in the "Order and Export" tab so I expected this to result in these 2 jars being exported to my Runtime class path.
However,  when I click "Run on Server" I get a ClassNotFound error.  I can fix this by modifying my Run configuration and adding the 2 jars to the classpath.

Is this an other manestification of the bug below?

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=118622

Answer (score 0):

It sounds possible. It sounds like it's not a bug per se, but a 'feature' of how the runtime classpath is managed in Eclipse when deploying to / running on an external server. Note the distinction between the runtime classpath (used by the server when running your application) and the build classpath (used by Eclipse when compiling your applicaiton).

In order to have the 2 jars on the runtime classpath they should be copied to "WEB-INF/lib" of your application's exploded directory (or within the war file).

Comment: What I find even stranger is I have to explicitly add Servlet-API.jar to my runtime class path.  How or why does Tomcat not pick this up?  In previous versions of Eclipse ( I'm using Juno now ) I never had to worry about servlet-API.  It just worked :(

Comment: What happens if you don't explicitly add it to the runtime classpath? Does the version of the servlet api your application is using correspond to the servlet api of the Tomcat you are using? You are correct that Tomcat should have this dependency included already.

Comment: I get a Class not found error for Servlet class if I don't export the ServletAPI jar.  In my IDE  my project references the Tomcat Server Runtime ( Added as a library )